# Ionic: Disqus embed loads locally, but not in production (or on an emulator)

Tags: ionic-framework, disqus

I've built a simple Android app, as a companion piece to a publication website, with the Ionic framework, and (after much head-banging), I managed to get the Disqus threads on the app to sync with those on the site. After trying a few different methods, I ended up going with [this directive from Michael Bromley](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils-disqus) to implement the Disqus widget in the app, which is hiding behind a "Comments" button at the bottom of each article on the app's UI.

Running with Ionic Serve, everything works brilliantly. Outside of the local server: not so much. I don't get an error message from Disqus – it simply doesn't load the iframe at all. I'm refraining from posting code, because I'm wondering if this is simply a CORS issue, or maybe something simple that I'm overlooking.

One thing that might be of importance: I don't have the Crosswalk plugin installed on the app – I'm not sure if my thinking is correct, here, but could it be possible that Disqus is compatible with Chrome, which is why it runs fine when I'm testing it on my browser, but isn't compatible with Android's default browser? I'm not extremely well-read on Crosswalk, but I believe it tells the app to use a specific browser – if so, could installing it fix the problem? I'd go ahead and install it, and see if it helps, but I'd like to avoid tampering too much with an otherwise-working app if the issue is something completely unrelated to the plugins.

One weird caveat: The Disqus comments loaded on *one* article just fine when I tested the app on Genymotion. I deleted that article, and created a new Test article on my site (thus firing up a new Disqus thread), and that failed to render on Genymotion. It seems very... random, I guess, that it would work once. It would seem that it would either work all the time, or never work.

EDIT: While running on Genymotion, no errors appear in the console when debugging the app with WebView. The fact that I'm not getting a "Refused to load" error makes me think that Disqus is getting called and, for whatever reason, is refusing to answer the phone at all.

Answer (score 0):

I can spend hours trying to figure something out, and then... well, as soon as I post a question, I end up figuring out the answer five minutes later.

I dug looked into the code for the directive I was using (which I highly recommend for anybody looking to easily implement Disqus into any AngularJS project), and I noticed that was calling for `embed.js` with the following string:

```
....

if (!$window.DISQUS) {
                        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
                        dsq.src = '//' + scope.config.disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
                        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
                    } else {

....
```

Amending `dsq.src = '//' + scope.config.disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';`to add a protocol, making it `dsq.src = 'http://' + scope.config.disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';`fixed the issue on Genymotion. I'll ship the updated APK to the Play Store, and comment on this answer to confirm whether or not it holds up there, as well.

Comment: Welp, it turns out that I won't be able to select my own answer, here. It turns fine on Genymotion, but won't load in production. So... rats.